# How to create an unknown number of img elements in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I have an unknown number of images which I need to put in my view.

- assets/images/

  - image1.jpg
  - image2.jpg
  - ...

How do I dynamically get these into my view?

I have tried creating an API GET endpoint which returns a list of relative paths for the view to use, but the images don't load because it requests http://localhost:8080/assets/images/image1.jpg#/home which just loads my app again, not the image. How can I dynamically load these images? Thanks.

```
<template>
  <div id="App">
    <img v-for="image in images" :src="image" alt="" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import api from '../APIService';

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
      return {
        images: []
      }
    },
    async beforeMount() {
      var images = await api.getImages();
      images.forEach(el => {
        this.images.push(el);
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what does `api.getImages` return?

Comment: An array of strings e.g. ['assets/images/image1.jpg', 'assets/images/image2.jpg']

Comment: The paths are relative to the component that is trying to render the images.

Comment: You need to make sure your image urls go through the webpack process because all images in `assets` folder are copied and renamed with the build. So basically you have to implement this in the `getImages` method. It might help if you share that method as well.

Comment: How do I make sure the urls go through webpack? I have tried the @ syntax as @Andrew1325 suggested but I the console error Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/images/placeholder.png'". getImages() is currently hardcoded to return the array of paths. I've been changing the hardcoded urls to try and get the correct format for Vue to render the images.

Answer (score 0):

could you try something like this:

```
<img v-for="image in images" :src="GetImage(image)" alt="" />
```

then have a method:

```
getImage(image) {
  let img = require('@/' + image)
  return img
}
```